# Nothing Seems To Get Enough Power...?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, refrigerator, stove

I just moved into a studio that someone is renting out. They just finished putting in a new kitchen, including a new fridge and stove. However, today is my first day here and I have already noticed a problem. First, the fridge is not cold enough. I have the settings turned all the way up, but there is hardly enough of a diference from room temp. On top of that, when I tried to cook, the stove does not heat up all of the way. I tried all the burners on high,but I still was not able to bring water to a boil or fry my food. Yeah, it heats up, but hardly.

It seems as if things turn on and they work, but not to the level that they should, especially with being brand new. What could be causing it?

Comment: Is the stove electric or gas?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a voltage issue, but you'd notice it in other places as well if it was.

Your ONLY recourse is to call the landlord and have them have someone check it. You CANNOT and should not do ANY electrical work in a place that you are renting.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the seals on the fridge door. Perhaps they are damaged or are not closing fully.

If it is an electric stove, it may be that it is of a type that you are not used to. Some electric stoves do take a longer time to reach full temperature. For example, halogen, inductive and resistive heating elements all have differing characteristics.

You could get the mains voltage checked.